# Scheme\DrRacket foldr

Tags: scheme, racket, fold

I'm trying to determine if a list of symbols got duplicates, if so I would like foldr to give me back a new list that each symbol appear only once

The idea is like that:

```
(define schema2 '(aa bb cc))

(define (schema? schema)
  (foldr (lambda (obj lst)
           (if (contains? lst obj)
               (lst)
               ((cons obj lst)))
           ) (list) schema))

(define (contains? list obj)
  (cond
    ((empty? list) #f)
    ((eq? (car list) obj) #t) 
    (else (contains? (cdr list) obj)))
  )

(schema? schema2)
```

But for some reason I'm getting an error of

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '(aa)
  arguments...: [none]
```

Comment: you have an extra pair of parentheses around `lst`, and also below, with the `cons`. Don't use `list` as a variable name. It's a built-in function, you'll get yourself in trouble because of that. Maybe `(list)` is not what you want there. Test it in the REPL. The error is telling you that `aa` is not a procedure, you gotta find why it is trying to apply a procedure with that name, where did it come from? Remember in scheme, the first symbol after an open paren is a procedure.

Comment: Thanks! Problem was ((cons obj lst)))

Comment: Dont delete the code from the question